# Using rx to insert word replacement

Tags: regular-expressions, rx

Been working on replacing regexps with the equivalent `rx` command, but the expression for `rx` is not producing the same result I get with the regexp.  For the word `counter`, the regexp expression gives `kter`, but `rx` gives `kktkekr`.

```
(rx (zero-or-more (or "col" "cog" "com" "con" "cor" "coun" "cum")))
```

This is the regexp I use that gets the required match

```
"\\<\\(co[glmnr]\\|coun\\|cum\\)"
```

Comment: Why `zero-or-more`?  The equivalent `rx` would be `(seq word-start (or "col" "cog" "com" "con" "cor" "coun" "cum"))`.

Comment: Using `seq` gives me `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function seq)`

Comment: You need `(rx (seq word-start (or "col" "cog" "com" "con" "cor" "coun" "cum")))`.

Comment: Right, forgot to look at it very carefully.

Comment: The `re-builder` command might be helpful to you here.

Comment: It is certainly a fantastic cool tool.

Comment: Although `emacs-lisp-mode` already does that.

Comment: As I mentioned on your other, similar question, please remove everything extraneous to your question, such as the use of `insert` and `replace-regexp-in-string`. Your question is **only** about the relation between what (1) `rx` gives for the arguments you give it and (2) the particular regexp you show.

Answer (score -1):

Further to @d125q's comment, the following expression solves the problem

```
(rx (seq word-start (or "col" "cog" "com" "con" "cor" "coun" "cum")))
```

Comment: As per your other question please credit the comment from @d125q that provided the answer